# How to mock ModelMetadata class using NSubstitute?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, nsubstitute

In my library I have a simple class:

```cs
public class FormDataJsonBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider 
{
    // code ommited

    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        // some logic
    }
}
```

And I want to test it, but to do so I have to somehow mock `ModelMetadata`(`context.Metadata` is type of `ModelMetadata`)  which is an `abstract` class with that signature:

```cs
public abstract class ModelMetadata : IEquatable<ModelMetadata?>, IModelMetadataProvider 
{
    // some props and methods

    internal virtual bool PropertyHasValidators => false; // problematic property :(
}
```

In my tests I have

```cs
[Test]
public void GetBinder_SimpleType_ShouldThrowException() 
{
    // Arrange
    var metadata = Substitute.For<ModelMetadata>();
    metadata.IsComplexType.Returns(false);
}
```

I get `System.ArgumentException : Can not instantiate proxy of class: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelMetadata. Could not find a parameterless constructor. (Parameter 'constructorArguments')` which is perfectly fair.

So. I've made a `TestModelMetadata` class:

```cs
public abstract class TestModelMetadata : ModelMetadata {
    public TestModelMetadata() : base(new ModelMetadataIdentity()) { }

    public new virtual bool IsComplexType { get; }

    public override IReadOnlyDictionary<object, object> AdditionalValues { get; }
    // More overridden props
}
```

and I'm using it like this:

```cs
public void GetBinder_SimpleType_ShouldThrowException() 
{
    // Arrange
    var metadata = Substitute.For<TestModelMetadata>();
    metadata.IsComplexType.Returns(false);
}
```

And here I get a strange exception:

```cs
System.TypeLoadException : Method 'get_PropertyHasValidators' on type 'Castle.Proxies.TestModelMetadataProxy' from assembly 'DynamicProxyGenAssembly2, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is overriding a method that is not visible from that assembly.
   at System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.CreateTypeNoLock()
   at System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.CreateTypeInfo()
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.Emitters.AbstractTypeEmitter.BuildType()
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.BaseClassProxyGenerator.GenerateType(String name, INamingScope namingScope)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.BaseProxyGenerator.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<GetProxyType>b__0(CacheKey cacheKey)
   at Castle.Core.Internal.SynchronizedDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.BaseProxyGenerator.GetProxyType()
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.DefaultProxyBuilder.CreateClassProxyType(Type classToProxy, Type[] additionalInterfacesToProxy, ProxyGenerationOptions options)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator.CreateClassProxyType(Type classToProxy, Type[] additionalInterfacesToProxy, ProxyGenerationOptions options)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator.CreateClassProxy(Type classToProxy, Type[] additionalInterfacesToProxy, ProxyGenerationOptions options, Object[] constructorArguments, IInterceptor[] interceptors)
   at NSubstitute.Proxies.CastleDynamicProxy.CastleDynamicProxyFactory.CreateProxyUsingCastleProxyGenerator(Type typeToProxy, Type[] additionalInterfaces, Object[] constructorArguments, IInterceptor[] interceptors, ProxyGenerationOptions proxyGenerationOptions)
   at NSubstitute.Proxies.CastleDynamicProxy.CastleDynamicProxyFactory.GenerateTypeProxy(ICallRouter callRouter, Type typeToProxy, Type[] additionalInterfaces, Object[] constructorArguments)
   at NSubstitute.Proxies.CastleDynamicProxy.CastleDynamicProxyFactory.GenerateProxy(ICallRouter callRouter, Type typeToProxy, Type[] additionalInterfaces, Object[] constructorArguments)
   at NSubstitute.Core.SubstituteFactory.Create(Type[] typesToProxy, Object[] constructorArguments, Boolean callBaseByDefault)
   at NSubstitute.Core.SubstituteFactory.Create(Type[] typesToProxy, Object[] constructorArguments)
   at NSubstitute.Substitute.For(Type[] typesToProxy, Object[] constructorArguments)
   at NSubstitute.Substitute.For[T](Object[] constructorArguments)
```

So the question is:

### How can I mock `ModelMetadata` class to use in my tests?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating a `TestModelMetadata` class just for the test, you should be able to tell NSubstitute to use one of the existing constructors on `ModelMetadata` like this:

```cs
[Test]
public void GetBinder_SimpleType_ShouldThrowException() 
{
    // Arrange
    var metadata = Substitute.For<ModelMetadata>(new ModelMetadataIdentity());
    metadata.IsComplexType.Returns(false);
}
```

Comment: This throwns an exception becuase of the logic in the `ModelMetadata` class, but when I am using `Substitute.For<ModelMetadata>(ModelMetadataIdentity.ForType(typeof(string))`, which looks perfectly good I get exception at `metadata.IsComplexType`: `NSubstitute.Exceptions.CouldNotSetReturnDueToNoLastCallException: Could not find a call to return from.`

Comment: I feel I am close to working with it. Plan B is I can just don't mock it, but this can make my tests not so clean as I want it to be

Comment: I see. Not sure what causes this :(